# Is there anything I should know before laying OSB underlayment on top of my subfloor?

Tags: underlayment, osb

I'm removing (painfully) all the particle board underlayment from the 1976 and replacing it with OSB so I can lay down some LVP.

The process seems simple. Lay down 4x8 sheets and screw into the joists and then cut and fit remaining pieces until the whole room is covered.

But are there any rules I should know? Do I need an expansion gap anywhere? Specific screws or a certain way I have to screw down the OSB?

Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure the tops of joists are all even with each other, so no dips/ridges in the floor.  A long straight edge should lay flat across the joists.  I think under 3/16 inch difference is allowed, check your flooring instructions.  Was the particle board damaged/swelled?

Comment: @crip659 There's definitely some dips in the floor. I imagine the only way to solve is to use floor patch? I was going to lay the underlayment, then look for dips and then fill. And there were a few spots in the particle board with swelling and moisture.

Comment: Dips you should be able to build up the joists/sister joists to have a flat floor, ridges can be shaved/cut down within limits.  Nicer to start with a flat floor than trying to fix after if the joists are handy to work on.